# More and more Threads are causing my app to lag

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my app I got some activities and a `ReceiverThread.class`.

The `Thread` is started from two different activities. And everytime I switch to another `Activity` and recall the former active `Activity` it starts a new `Thread`. So if I do some test on my app for about 10 Minutes or the app is simply used for some time, there is a mass of Threads open and all do the same.
Most of the time the Threads are on `TimedWait`.

This gives me wrong data and causes the app to lag hard, sometimes its not even responding.

Is there a good possibility to stop a thread `onPause()` or `onStop()` ? Because many of the methods are deprecated. Or how to resume a previous started Thread and so prevent the `Activity` from creating a new one?

This is my `ReceiverThread.run()`:

```
public void run() {
    initiateCAN();
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60);
            mHandler.post(r);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If something is not clear or missing, please feel free to ask and I will edit my post, but don't just simply downvote.

Comment: instead of `while (true)` you can use a flag that you can control to stop the thread `while (!stop)`. But you should have a look at Android Services: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: as I read in the first `Caution!`-section, I still have to use threading, because Services run in the Mainthread, so I cant see the benefit of using Services

Comment: The document states (unless you specify otherwise). So you can use the service to create a Thread (only one Thread that is running as long as the Service is running) and pass your data to the service and it will pass it to the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to do this is to use the built-in interrupt system. You can then stop the thread  by calling `Thread.interrupt()` (best in `onPause()` if you don't want multiple instances). Your run method would need to be somewhat changed:

```
public void run() {
    initiateCAN();
    try {
        while (!isInterrupted()) {
            Thread.sleep(60);
            mHandler.post(r);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

While this might work, it's still better to use a `Service` or another way to make sure there is only one instance at one time (maybe fragments instead of activities?).

Comment: where should I call `.interrupt()`? `onPause()` or `onStop()`

Comment: So this works now fine for me and as I'm a very bad programmer and also have not much time (have to finish my bachelor thesis), I hope this will do its duty until I got my grades ;P

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Services, and that service starts the thread. When you switch the activity, the services is running and not is necessary start a new thread.

Comment: If Pescis' answer does not work I'll have to try that. But I never worked with Services, I hope I'll get it fast enough to work